# Cancelling multiple tasks by registering callbacks on cancellation tokens

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cancellation, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have the following code piece with the output below.
I was expecting the second task to be cancelled as it also registers a callback on the cancellation token.
But the cancellation only happens on the first task, where the original cancellation was done. 
Aren't cancellations supposed to be propagated to all token instances?
The [Microsoft article on Cancellation Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) does not explain this well.

Any pointers on why this is happening?

Code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncProgramming();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async void AsyncProgramming()
        {

            try
            {
                using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
                {
                    var task2 = CreateTask2(cts);
                    var task1 = CreateTask1(cts);

                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    await Task.WhenAll(task2, task1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Both tasks over");
        }

        private static async Task CreateTask1(CancellationTokenSource cts)
        {
            try
            {
                cts.Token.Register(() => { cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); });
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("This is task one");
                cts.Cancel();
                Console.WriteLine("This should not be printed because the task was cancelled");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task 1 exception: " + e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Task 1 was cancelled");
            }

        }

        private static async Task CreateTask2(CancellationTokenSource cts)
        {
            try
            {
                cts.Token.Register(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Write something");
                    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
                    cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                });
                await Task.Delay(8000);

                Console.WriteLine("This is task two");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task 2 was cancelled by Task 1");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
This is task one
Write something
Task 1 exception: Thread was being aborted.
Task 1 was cancelled
This is task two
Thread was being aborted.
Both tasks over
```

Comment: First you don't need `Register` there - it has different purpose. Second, calling `Cancel` right from the task as well as dealing `CancellationTokenSource` isn't considered as good practice - your first cancellation works only by coincidence, because all exceptions inside the `Register` callback are propagated to `Cancel` method.

Comment: Why do you call `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()`? This completely messes up your demo. The tasks are not cancelled, you are just aborting the main thread of your application! The error messages are misleading too. Don't print messages like "Task 1 was cancelled" inside a generic exception handler. Catch specific exceptions (`OperationCanceledException` or `TaskCanceledException`) to print such messages. In the generic exception handler it is preferable to print the `Exception.ToString()` to see the whole thing, not the `Exception.Message` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is that when you call `CancellationToken.Register` all it normally does is to store the delegate to call later.

The thread/logic flow calling `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` runs all previously registered delegates, regardless of where those were registered from. This means any exception thrown in those normally does not relate in any way to the methods that called *Register*.

**Side note 1:** I said *normally* above, because there is a case where the call to `Register` will run the delegate right away. I think this is why the msdn documentation is extra confusing. Specifically: if the token was already cancelled, then `Register` will run the delegate right away, instead of storing it to be ran later. Underneath that happens in [`CancellationTokenSource.InternalRegister`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs).

The second thing to complete the picture is that all `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` does is to throw an exception wherever it is being ran from. That would normally be wherever `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` was called from. Note that normally all registered delegates are ran, even if some of those throw an exception.

**Side note 2:** throwing `ThreadAbortException` changes the intended logic in the `Cancel` method, because that special exception can't be caught. When faced with that, cancel stops running any further delegates. The same happens to the calling code, even when catching exceptions.

The last thing to note, is that the presence of the CancellationToken does not affect the logic flow of the methods. All lines in the method run, unless there is code explicitely exiting the method, for example, by throwing an exception. This is what happens if you pass the cancellation token to the Task.Delay calls and it gets cancelled from somewhere else before the time passes. It is also what happens if you were to put calls to `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` after specific lines in your method.

Comment: So both the callbacks get registered and are executed in the context of the request/thread which cancels the token by calling cts.Cancel. Since the callback is never executed in the context of the second task, the exception is never thrown in the second task, and it executes normally. Both the callbacks are executed in the context of the first task, hence the first task never completes and throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

It is not just the second task that fails to cancel. Both registrations to the token work and both `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` fire, but they are not handled because they run in a different thread.

This happens in the background (twice):

> An exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

What you should do is call `cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` in your function instead of registering to the event.

See the examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads

Right now you are combining two ways of cancellation: registering to the token cancel event (`Token.Register`), and throwing if the token is cancelled (`Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`).

Either you subscribe to the cancel event and perform your own cancel/cleanup logic, or you check in your function code if you should cancel your operation.

An example would look like this:

```
private static async Task CreateTask2(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        // Pass on the token when calling other functions.
        await Task.Delay(8000, token);

        // And manually check during long operations.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            // Do we need to cancel?
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // Simulating work.
            Thread.SpinWait(5000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("This is task two");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task 2 was cancelled by Task 1");
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work but I dont understand what you mean by the execution is awaiting the Task.Delay.Why does the execution not resume after the delay?

Comment: That is the same article I used for reference but it does not have anything about this.

Comment: You're mixing object and operation cancellation. In your task, just call the `Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` without registering.

Comment: How did adding the ```await Task.Delay(8000,cts.Token)``` help?

Comment: Passing the token to the `Delay` makes the delay cancel itself when the token fires. Because your cancel fires after 5000ms (from task 1), it happens while task 2 is still waiting for it's 8000ms delay which then cancels itself.

Comment: But without passing the token to Delay in task 2, task 2 was executing without any cancellation. In the o/p, "This is task two" was getting printed.

Comment: Yes, passing the token to the `Task.Delay` made the delay listen to the token in a correct way and therefore cancel itself. It was the delay throwing the cancel exception, not your `Register()` handler. I've added an example of how you would check for cancellation instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193464/discussion-between-ayushmati-and-willem).

Comment: `Right now you are combining two ways of cancellation: registering to the token cancel event `, `Register` isn't a way of cancellation it's just notification, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Registration of a delegate by `Register` is just a way to notify when a token goes to the cancelled state, no more. In order to do the cancellation you need to react on this notification in the code and it's mostly needed when execution you want to cancel goes to a stage where cancellation token isn't verified (for example because a method being executed just doesn't accept `CancellationToken` as paramater) but you still need some control of cancellation state. But in all cases when you deal with executuon of code which has access to `CancellationToken` you just don't need to subscribe on the cancellation notification.

In your case the first delegate raises exception and this exception is propagated to the `Cancel` call only that's why the task is cancelled, but this is improper design as you shouldn't deal with `CancellationTokenSource` in your tasks and shouldn't initiate a cancellation in there, so I'd say that the first cancellation works only by coincidence. For the second task the delegate is invoked but nothing triggers the cancellation inside the task so why should it be cancelled ?